# Why is my null check against my string not working?

Tags: java, android

Alright here we go.

I am probably asking the most popular question on here and I'm freaking seasoned dev.

Basically I am comparing if a String is null. **IT IS NULL** But sadly, it is for some reason bypassing my if and going straight for my else.

I feel ashamed and guilty for asking this oh so simple question but I am at a loss.

What am I missing?

Relevant Code:

```
  Log.i(TAG,"mBeforeId..." + mBeforeId);
            if(mBeforeId == null){
                Log.i(TAG,"mBeforeId INSIDE IF..." + mBeforeId);
                 Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"These are no current listings before these.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else{
                getSubReddit(mSubReddit, Constants.HOT_CATEGORY, mBeforeId, null);
            }
```

LogCat:

```
 12-31 13:34:04.139  10383-10383/com.android.finalproject.tubbsreddit I/SubRedditFragment﹕ mBeforeId...null
```

As you can clearly see, It is saying mBeforeId is null but it refuses to go to my if and makes pals with my else.

GAR.

Comment: Multi thread? Anyway use a debugger to check

Comment: was it compiled properly ? try uninstalling app and installing again on emulator

Comment: Yeah well the value is coming from a background thread but it is clearly null when it reaches my `if` statement.  I've tried debugging and it is still `null`. Pretty Frustrating.

Comment: App compiles fine and runs properly. All other code is doing fine.

Comment: It's not completely clear given the single log entry shown. Why don't you remove the keyboard smashing, replace it with something clear, and add another log cat to the else case. It helps to be *very* explicit in cases like this.

Comment: Alright, give me a sec.

Comment: It's not null. It might be the *string* `"null"`, but it's clearly not the *value* `null`.

Comment: Tried if(mBeforeId == null || mBeforeId.length() == 0) and tried printing Log statement multiple times. Same result.

Comment: @DaveNewton Ha, that works. Aparently Reddit API makes the value "null" not `null`. Can't believe I didn't think about that. Thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

In Android Log statements, if you try to print a String which has null value, it throws an exception. This might be the reason why you are seeing this unexpected behavior.

Try to remove the log cat statements if the value is null. It might work. Give a try

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it.

Basically

`mBeforeId` was "null", not `null`.  It was the actual string "null".

Don't you just love programming?